# Select rows where a column matches a predicate or has a null value and replace null values.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve rows from table where column value in 'Test1' and 'Test2' and retrieve NULL values with 'No value found'. The following query is not working. Please let me know.

```
SELECT address_id, ISNULL(city, 'No value found') AS city from 
Address where city in ('Test1', 'Test2')
```

Comment: Please elaborate, "The following query is not working" is a little too broad.  what is the error you get?  Or, does it just not return what you want ? The query as written will only return records where the city is 'Test1' or 'Test2'.  It will never return a row where city is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but maybe this will help:

```
SELECT address_id, ISNULL(city, 'No value found') AS city
FROM Address
WHERE ((city is null) or (city in ('Test1','Test2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, City is not matching your predicate. Which [happens before](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm) you get to the select part. Please try

```
SELECT address_id, ISNULL(city, 'No value found') AS city from 
Address where city is null or city in ('Test1', 'Test2')
```